# How to understand Composite Primary Key when it comes to storage (in Mysql)?

Tags: mysql, database-internals, data-pages, btree

I can image how rows will be arranged in a single database page as primary key order (example an auto-increment key) after reading this [post](https://blog.jcole.us/2013/01/10/btree-index-structures-in-innodb/). But I wonder how it will in the case of composite primary keys. For example consider a pk(a integer, b integer), whether the rows are arranged as per column a or by column b in the database page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This answer is focused on MySQL; in particular, the InnoDB Engine.  JCole's blog (which you linked to) is valid for InnoDB, but might be overly technical.  I'll try to give a lighter answer.)

Think of a composite key this way...  Concatenate the keys together, then the BTree structure is just as if it had a single-column (though larger) key.

The order of the columns specified in any composite index matters.  For `PRIMARY KEY(a,b)`, the rows will be in this order:

```
a b
- -
1 1
1 2
1 5
1 7
2 1
2 2
2 3
2 8
3 2
...
```

This means, for example, that `WHERE a=2` will find all the rows "clustered" together.  But `WHERE b=2` will find them scattered.

"Clustering" is also used here to say that the data is right next to the PK in the same BTree.

The block structure (16KB blocks in InnoDB) is controlled by whatever happens.  That is, there is no obvious place in the pair (a,b) where one block ends and the next starts.

In InnoDB, the `PRIMARY KEY` is always clustered with the data.  As a side effect, there is virtually zero overhead for that one KEY.  All "secondary keys" are separate BTrees that have the PK in their leaf nodes.

In the above example, let's say (for conciseness) that there were only 3 rows per Block:

```
Block 0:  (1,1),(1,2),(1,5)
Block 1:  (1,7),(2,1),(2,2)
Block 2:  (2,3),(2,8),(3,2)
```

Note that the breaks in `a` are unrelated to the Block splits.  (Also, this example may be misleading -- Blocks rarely have as few as 3 rows; Blocks do not necessarily have the same number of rows each.)

Comment: can I get your help to understand this statement in your answer -----"The block structure (16KB blocks in InnoDB) is controlled by whatever happens. That is, there is no obvious place in the pair (a,b) where one block ends and the next starts."

Comment: @DineshKumar - You said "whether the rows are arranged as per column a or by column b in the database page" -- I was saying that the "pages" (aka blocks??) are handled independently of "per column a or ..."

Comment: I read that a row inside a single database page has pointer to other row which is next in the increasing order of pk. So how it will be in case of composite pk

Comment: @DineshKumar - Imagine concatenating the columns of a composite key together.  In my example, 11->12->15->...

Comment: @DineshKumar - I don't know if the individual rows are linked with a 'pointer' of ordered by some other means.  It's not very relevant; somehow they can _very quickly_ find any _specific_ row from the 100 or so in a block.  And then find the _next_ row.  Finally, when the end of the block is encountered, there is some kind of "pointer" to the "next" block.  JCole's blog _may_ have gotten into those kinds of details.

Comment: @DineshKumar - are you asking from a Computer Science theoretical point of view?  Or as a database user point of view?  I have both backgrounds.  Wearing my CS hat, I can envision serveral different ways to structure the rows in a block.  But I don't care enough to find out _which way_ was chosen.  Wearing my User hat, I can see where it works efficiently and where it does not.

Comment: I'm a CS engineer working in Mysql DB. BTW, these two lines were there in that post: 1.For both leaf and non-leaf pages, each record (including the infimum and supremum system records) contain a “next record” pointer, which stores an offset (within the page) to the next record. 2. The records are not physically ordered within the page (they take whatever space is available at the time of insertion); their only order comes from their position in the linked list.

Comment: @DineshKumar - OK.  That sounds like the Block is composed of a doubly-linked-list of "rows".  One of many ways to store and maintain the info.  (I might have chosen a different way.)  That tells me they are 'ordered', but finding a specific row may be Order(N) unless there is something like a binary tree overlaying it; I doubt there is - it would add too much complexity.

Comment: So, I am understanding that if mysql were able to store 4 rows per page (just an assumption :P) then as per your example the first page will have (1,1),(1,2),(1,5),(1,7) and the next page will have (2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,8).. Upvote this comment i were right so we can end this thread

Comment: @DineshKumar - Yes.  And 3/page -- (1,1),(1,2),(1,5), then (1,7)(2,1),(2,2), then (2,3),(2,8),... would better exemplify that the values of `a` do not relate to the Block splits.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesnt (to my knowledge) deviate from standards here. Explained wellin the answer to this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648217/what-does-a-b-tree-index-on-more-than-1-column-look-like

Comment: That link is tagged multiple Database Engines _other than_ MySQL.  So, be cautious about any conclusions that you get from it.